# Updating package.json based on package-lock.json npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

So I have a package-lock.json file and a package.json file. When trying to do `npm install` with just the package.json file, I am getting the below failure:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for static-eval@2.0.2.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

The thing is, it installs fine when the package-lock.json is present, so I'm sure it must be an issue with versioning somewhere. The problem is I'm not sure what dependency is pulling in the wrong version. How could I go about finding out what versions to set in package.json?

My current package.json looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@trv-tds/core": "^7.8.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^29.0.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^29.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^3.0.6",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-form-stepper": "^2.0.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactflow": "^11.8.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Is there a proper way to update it or find out what's causing this issue?

I've tried

- removing the package.json and using npm init to recreate it with versions from node_modules, but npm install still fails in that situation with the same error
- Installing different versions of static-eval, it still ends up failing no matter what
- Looking at node_modules when successfully installed using package-lock.json, I don't even see static-eval there, so I can't find the version if any used

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily answering the question, but I was able to find out it's due to  our internal Nexus Repository, as installing the package manually seems to work from a .tar file while it's not being served properly from the repo.

As a workaround for repo issues you can download the package and install it with:
`npm install /package-path/package.tgz`